# Sketching sets in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This might seem too elementary but I'm teaching myself complex analysis and have very minor doubts about the following sets. I'm asked to sketch:

A. $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |e^{z^2}| \le e \}$

B. $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(\frac{2}{z})<1 \}$

My Approach: For A, $$|e^{z^2}|= \sqrt{(e^{z^2})^2}\le e$$ Therefore, $$e^{z{^4}} \le e^2$$ I get, $$x^4+y^4 \le 2.$$ Am I doing this right?

For B, I get $y>2$. Is this right?

Comment: This is not right since $z\in\mathbb{C}$, you cannot have $e^{z^4}\leq e^2$, what if $z=i\pi/2$?

Comment: also if $z=a+bi$ then $z^4\ne a^4+b^4$

Comment: Oops I put the wrong work. I will edit right now.

Comment: For the first question, we want the **real** part of $z^2$ to be $\le 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ah I see is that what the $|  |$ symbol means? I mean I thought it meant length? Square root of $x^2 + y^2$

Comment: $|w|$ gives the distance of the complex number $w$ from $0$.  Usually it is called the norm.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why do I ignore the imaginary part though?

Comment: Because $e^{a+ib}=e^ae^{ib}$, and $e^{ib}$ has norm $1$, it is $\cos b+i\sin b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wow how could I have forgotten that. Thanks! Is part B right?

Comment: If we let $z=x+iy$, multiply top and bottom of $\frac{2}{x+iy}$ by $x-iy$. The imaginary part turns out to be $-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$. That;s what you want to be $\lt 1$. For the geometry, note that $-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}=1$ is $x^2+y^2+2y=0$, a circle.